# Consolidate xmlns attributes to the root element?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I'm converting a set of XML documents from one format, which doesn't include namespace prefixes, to another, which does.
Everything is relatively straightforward, but it's a bit repetitive in the XMLNS output. Below is an example.

#### (Very Simple) Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a/>
```

#### XSLT

```
<!-- xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" -->

<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"

    xmlns:a="urn:data.test-a"
    xmlns:b="urn:data.test-b"
    xmlns:c="urn:data.test-c"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:local.test schema/test.xsd"

    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/a">
        <xsl:element name="a:test-a">
            <!-- attempted fix -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>

            <!-- is there a better way to get this in there? -->
            <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation">urn:local.test schema/test.xsd</xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:element name="b:test-b">
                <xsl:element name="c:test-c">content</xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>

        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a:test-a
    xmlns:a="urn:data.test-a"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:local.test schema/test.xsd">
  <b:test-b xmlns:b="urn:data.test-b">
    <c:test-c xmlns:c="urn:data.test-c">content</c:test-c>
    <c:test-c xmlns:c="urn:data.test-c">content</c:test-c>
  </b:test-b>
  <b:test-b xmlns:b="urn:data.test-b">
    <c:test-c xmlns:c="urn:data.test-c">content</c:test-c>
    <c:test-c xmlns:c="urn:data.test-c">content</c:test-c>
  </b:test-b>
</a:test-a>
```

#### Desired Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a:test-a
    xmlns:a="urn:data.test-a"
    xmlns:b="urn:data.test-b"
    xmlns:c="urn:data.test-c"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:local.test schema/test.xsd">
  <b:test-b>
    <c:test-c>content</c:test-c>
    <c:test-c>content</c:test-c>
  </b:test-b>
  <b:test-b>
    <c:test-c>content</c:test-c>
    <c:test-c>content</c:test-c>
  </b:test-b>
</a:test-a>
```

Basically, I want to consolidate the namespace attributes into the root element.
I've been doing some research and I thought I had this locked up using  as seen [here](http://lenzconsulting.com/namespaces-in-xslt/#xslt_1_0__copying_namespace_nodes_using_the_namespace_axis). But, it's not having the desired effect; I assume I'm either using it incorrectly or am restricted by xsltproc's capabilities.

Performing a second pass to clean up the XMLNS entries would be a fine solution as well.

Also, in case it restricts a solution, I think my environment will be limited to XSLT 1.0.

Thanks for any tips.

PS. A smaller question is if there's a better way to get that schemaLocation attribute in the output, but that's minor.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and complete solution in a better writing style, and also for a recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is probably the shortest transformation that satisfies your requirements**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

    xmlns:a="urn:data.test-a"
    xmlns:b="urn:data.test-b"
    xmlns:c="urn:data.test-c"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:local.test schema/test.xsd">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <a:test-a xmlns:a="urn:data.test-a"
           xmlns:b="urn:data.test-b"
           xmlns:c="urn:data.test-c"
           xsi:schemaLocation="urn:local.test schema/test.xsd">
            <b:test-b>
                <c:test-c>content</c:test-c>
            </b:test-b>
        </a:test-a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is performed on the provided XML document**:

```
<a/>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a:test-a xmlns:a="urn:data.test-a"
   xmlns:b="urn:data.test-b"
   xmlns:c="urn:data.test-c"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:local.test schema/test.xsd">
   <b:test-b>
      <c:test-c>content</c:test-c>
   </b:test-b>
</a:test-a>
```

**However, be warned**: Placing all namespace nodes at the top element, even when they are not needed there, is not a recommended practice, because all namespace nodes are copied to all descendent elements and this leads to waste of a lot of memory.

Comment: Ah, so you just directly insert them.  Thanks for the tip.  I can appreciate the memory concerns. At this stage the goal is to mirror the sample files. It'll be easy enough to switch to a more efficient, if also more verbose, option when it's ready for deployment.

Comment: "all namespace nodes are copied to all descendent elements" - since the spec doesn't specify implementation, only semantics, isn't it true that a processor only needs to behave *as if* all namespace nodes are copied to all descendant elements? Or expressed another way, all descendant nodes have all the ancestors' namespace nodes (unless shadowed), but this doesn't mean that in the processor implementation they must necessarily be separate copies?

Comment: @LarsH: The namespace nodes "belong to" all descendent nodes and in practice, for efficiency reasons, they are also copied. You can see hhow many namespace nodes are there by simply count() -ing them. This result clearly shows that more namespace nodes exist when all namespaces are at the top element than when the namespaces are located where they are really necessary.

Comment: `count()` must show a result as if namespace nodes are on all descendants, because the spec says semantically they are there; but that does not imply that a particular XSLT processor implements this by making physical copies of the namespace node data structures. I'm willing to take your word for it that most do, but it seems strange that they would do that "for efficiency reasons" if the memory cost is so high, O(n)... while the time cost of looking up the ancestor axis is O(log(n))... or better, if you have a smart implementation that could copy namespace nodes on demand.

Comment: @LarsH: The implementors probably tried both ways and chose the more efficient implementation :)

Comment: It creates a root node attribute  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/" in the resulting XML. What should I do to have xmlns="MY_CUSTOM_URL" in the resulting XML ?

Comment: No, With all my 9 different XSLT processors the result is the one that is in this answer. You must be using some non-compliant/buggy XSLT processor.